# Translating Pan Gesture Coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I've added a pan gesture to a `UILabel` that contains a number. When the user pans up or down, I want the number to go up/down. I've got this working fine - panning up 24 coordinates decreases the number by 24, etc.

What I need to do now is make it so that the number only gets incremented at intervals of 20 coordinates - so, when the coordinate is between 50 and 70, the number gets incremented by 50, when the coordinate is between 100 and 120, the number gets incremented by 100, and so on.

How can I do this without adding a huge `if/else` tree for every single case? I'm sure there's a very simple way to do it, perhaps using a `for` loop, but my tired brain can't seem to wrap its head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How bout some basic maths and trimming off the precision.

```
static NSInteger BasicNormalize(CGFloat input, CGFloat interval)
{
  NSInteger units = (input + interval / 2.f) / interval;
  return units * interval;
}
```

By adding half of the interval to start you get some basic rounding. e.g. 9 rounds down to 0 and 11 rounds up to 20

Answer (score 0):

You can normalise the value. Try this code:

```
        CGPoint loc = [sender locationInView:self];

        int y = (int)loc.y / 20;
        y = y * 20;
        myValue += y;
```